Random "owl-carousel is not a function" Error in Porto Theme (Version 4.0.8) on Magento 2.4.7 CE
I am encountering a sporadic "owl-carousel is not a function" error on the front-end of my Magento 2.4.7 CE store using the Porto theme (version 4.0.8). The issue occurs randomly, making it difficult to identify the root cause. The console error seems to indicate that the Owl Carousel library is not being properly loaded or initialized at times.
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function


Steps Taken:
Ensured Owl Carousel is Included: Verified that owl.carousel.min.js is
included in the page.
Checked RequireJS Configuration: Confirmed that requirejs-config.js
has the correct paths and shims for owl.carousel.
Cleared Cache: Ran bin/magento cache:clean and bin/magento cache:flush.
Deployed Static Content: Executed bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f.
Verified jQuery Loading: Made sure jQuery is loaded before Owl Carousel.
Debugged with Browser Console: Inspected for other JavaScript errors that might interfere with Owl Carousel.

Has anyone faced a similar issue with the Porto theme or Magento 2.4.7 CE?
What could be the potential reasons for this random error?
What additional steps can I take to debug and resolve this issue?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Yes I am facing same issue anyone can you please help this issue

As per discussion with porto theme support,
They don't have any fix available for this as the issue only persist when MergeCSS option is off and thus Enabling MergeCSS should fix the problem
